# Formula for multiplicative distance in Latex

Tags: math-mode, amsmath

I would like to display the below formula in Latex :

[image]

How to display the formula in Latex ?

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! `\[ \biggl(\prod_{i=1}^M (1+|x_i - y_i|)\biggr) \]` should do it – I supposed `abs` denoted the absolute value.

Comment: For a good `\abs` command use `mathtools` and define it via `\DeclarePairedDelimiter\abs\lvert\rvert` and then use `\abs{...}` to get `\lvert ... \rvert`. It can also scale in cerain ways. Note that using `|....|` directly is not recommended (use `\lvert ... \rvert`), what can be seen via `|-1| vs \lvert -1 \rvert`

Comment: Is it essential to use a Times Roman math font? Please advise.

Comment: @Mico : Not necessary to use Times Roman font. The default latex font is fine

Comment: @Bernard: I think you forgot to add -1 in your latex code. Your latex code just displays the bracket content. And yes, abs denote the absolute values

Comment: @user3046211: It seems I forgot to read up to the end. Is the code I proposed  convenient, after it has been completed?

Comment: @Bernard: yeah, it's convenient, I was able to add that '-1' to the end by myself, and it worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are two possible solutions, the first with and the second without the large parentheses. Speaking for myself, I'd prefer the second solution, as the large parentheses are not needed to begin with. Your readers will likely appreciate your efforts to reduce visual clutter.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools} % for '\DeclarePairedDelimiter' macro
\DeclarePairedDelimiter\abs\lvert\rvert % define an '\abs' macro
%\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath} % optional, for Times Roman text and math font
\begin{document}
\[
\biggl( \, \prod_{i=1}^M \bigl(1+\abs{x_i-y_i}\bigr) \! \biggr) - 1
\qquad
\prod_{i=1}^M \bigl(1+\abs{x_i-y_i}\bigr) - 1
\]
\end{document}
```